# How do I insert all actions into unity?

Tags: animation, unity, actions

I have been trying to get all my actions into unity for hours now and I can't get it to work, I have enabled the F thing, and I tried a lot of solutions including ones that I have tried my self, but none seem to get all my actions into unity. The only action that is being imported is the one that I have selected and shows in the NLA that it is selected, but other than that I can't get any other action to come with the file

**I directly drag in the .blend file into unity btw**

Comment: "I directly drag in the .blend file into unity btw" That may be the problem. Did you try exporting in FBX then importing it into Unity ?

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks...  I feel dumb...

Comment: You shouldn't feel dumb, dragging and dropping files should be working imho - but it isn't.